# Skrill does not return ipn?

Tags: payment

I'm implement skrill payment in my website. But in the final step, after successfully pay my products, Skrill do not return status and transaction id to me. Please help me how to get transaction id from skrill.

Comment: are you making like a Paypal IPN? Are you sure that Skrill have a IPN, I think it don't have. :) Can you explain more or elaborate what you are doing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. 
Maybe you can try to redirect *.cgi file
And in live site, not local